# yii2 mandrill mail is sent but not insert contain

Tags: php, email, templates, yii2, mandrill

How to insert contain into mandrill template using yii2 **nickcv** plugin. in this code **test.org** is my template name and i want to insert into contain. anyone have idea about it.
This is the code.

```
\Yii::$app->mailer
->compose('test.org')
->setTo('test@mail.com')
->setSubject($setSubject)
->send();
```

i just want to add body like this

```
$body = "Hi ,Testing here";
```

Comment: does not insert contain ?

Comment: Yes i also use setTemplateData('test.org1',$params); where $param = array(      'html' => '<div>' . $body . '</div>',);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `setHtmlBody` function just like that

```
$mailSent = Yii::$app->mailer
                ->compose($template_name)
                ->setFrom('test@mail.org')
                ->setTo($to_email)
                ->setSubject($setSubject)
                ->setHtmlBody($setTextBody['html'])
                ->send();
        return $mailSent;
```